# MongoDB find $near and aggregate $geoNear return different results

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Why does find and aggregate return a different amount of documents here?
I have no glue why. Is this a bug or what do i wrong here?
I have this small peace of code for mongo db shell. I look only for documents which within a certain radius from a given location.
**geojson_loc** is a 2dsphere index and the **only** index on this collection. Thx for any explanation which might explain what i am doing wrong here.

Code:

```
db = new Mongo("localhost").getDB("dbname");
print("All docs:"+db.coll.find().count())

docs = db.coll.find({"geojson_loc":{"$near" :{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", 
    "coordinates": [11.575433, 48.137289]}, "$maxDistance" : 20000.0 }}}).count()
print("with find:"+docs)

cc = db.coll.aggregate({'$geoNear': {'spherical': true, 'limit': 1500000, 
'near': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [11.575433, 48.137289]}, 'maxDistance': 20000.0, 'distanceField':
'temp.distance'}})
count = 0;

cc.forEach(function(doc){
count++;});

print("with aggregate:"+ count);
```

The result is:
All docs: 25000
with find: 13000
with aggregate: 4000

And i would expect:
All docs: 25000
with find: 13000
with aggregate: 13000
or:
All docs: 25000
with find: 4000
with aggregate: 4000

**EDIT:**
If I run $geoNear without aggregation it returns the same amount of documents as within aggregation. The size of the returned document is 88MB which probably exceeds the 16MB limit of maximum BSON document size which can be returned. Is there are way to use $geoNear within aggregation without this restriction in size or $near which is not possible at all as far I know?

Comment: I see you are using $geoNear in aggregation stage. Try using it without aggregation and see what does it return? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/ It would be fair comparison if you use both geoNear and near in aggregation or without aggregation.

Comment: Use $geoNear without aggregation framework.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and I guess the problem ist that $geoNear returns a single document which is limited to maximum BSON size. The returned file is 88MB as PLANE JSON which is likely to exceed the 16MB maximum document size for bson.

Comment: Yes. You are right. $geoNear is limited to 16 MB.

Comment: You can try to project absolutely needed fields only. This will help you mitigate size limitations to some extent.

Comment: I have already tried this, but there are too many documents. Thus, this is unfortunately no solution. However thx a lot for your help.